# For loop is not placing text in InfoWindows Google Maps API from array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am running a for loop to go through all countries and place a marker with the GDP from the World Bank API.

I was able to run the for loop and get all the coordinates from Google Maps Geocoding, but I cannot place the text with the GDP value in the InfoWindows.

It is showing only Zimbabwe when you press any marker. Why is that? How can I fix it? Thanks a lot.

```
var map;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(25, 25),
    });
    var url = 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG?date=2015&per_page=264&format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata';
    var query_url = url;

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = query_url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

window.Getdata = function(data) {
    var country_gdp = data[1].map(function(item) {
        return {
            country: item.country.value,
            value: item.value,
        }
    });

    for (i = 0; i < country_gdp.length; i++) {
        GDP_country_growth = country_gdp[i];
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.addEventListener('load', processResponse);
        xhttp.open('GET', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + GDP_country_growth.country + '&key=YOURAPIKEYHERE');
        xhttp.send();
        var processResponse = function() {
            var coordinates = JSON.parse(this.response);
            console.log(coordinates);

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates.results[0].geometry.location.lat, coordinates.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
            var contentString = 'The GDP of ' + GDP_country_growth.country + ' is ' + GDP_country_growth.value;
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString,
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                contentString: contentString
            });
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(this.contentString);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
                map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two issues: 1. the geocoder is asynchronous.  2. you are running into the quota/rate limit for the geocoder. (the Zimbabwe result is due to the asynchronous nature of the geocoder)

Comment: The quota limit can be solved with my API key I suppose. But how can I solve the problem of the geocoder being asynchronous?

Comment: The quota limit isn't the issue. The issue is the rate limit, which the key doesn't affect.

Comment: Alright. Well, I did almost the same code, but with a request of the lat and lng to the World Bank API. Still getting the last result as Zimbabwe. Any idea how to sync the marker with the infowindow? I can get the marker in every position, but not the correct GDP value in the InfoWindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the association of the infowindow data with the geocoded location, one option is to use function closure (the function below gets closure on GDP_country_growth, the element of the array that is used for the geocoding request):

```
function processCountry(GDP_country_growth) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var processResponse = function() {
    var coordinates = JSON.parse(this.response);
    console.log(coordinates);

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates.results[0].geometry.location.lat, coordinates.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
    var contentString = 'The GDP of ' + GDP_country_growth.country + ' is ' + GDP_country_growth.value;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      contentString: contentString
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(this.contentString);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
      map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
    });
  }
  xhttp.addEventListener('load', processResponse);
  xhttp.open('GET', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + GDP_country_growth.country);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mta8vtuo/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25, 25),
  });
  var url = 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG?date=2015&per_page=264&format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata';
  var query_url = url;

  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = query_url;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

window.Getdata = function(data) {
  var country_gdp = data[1].map(function(item) {
    return {
      country: item.country.value,
      value: item.value,
    }
  });

  for (i = 0; i < country_gdp.length; i++) {
    (function(country_info) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        processCountry(country_info);
      }, 1000 * i);
    })(country_gdp[i])
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

function processCountry(GDP_country_growth) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var processResponse = function() {
    var coordinates = JSON.parse(this.response);
    console.log(coordinates);

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates.results[0].geometry.location.lat, coordinates.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
    var contentString = 'The GDP of ' + GDP_country_growth.country + ' is ' + GDP_country_growth.value;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      contentString: contentString
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(this.contentString);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
      map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
    });
  }
  xhttp.addEventListener('load', processResponse);
  xhttp.open('GET', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + GDP_country_growth.country);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: I tried to get the lat and lng from another source, that is the World Bank countries array. I wrote the code just as your example. But the InfoWindow showed again Zimbabwe, any thoughts on that?

Comment: var url_countries = 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/' + GDP_country_growth.countryid + '?' + 'format=jsonp&prefix=Getdata1';
var query_url_countries = url_countries;
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = query_url_countries;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
Getdata1 = function(data) {
var country_data = data[1].map(function(item) {
    return {
    country: item.name,
    longitude: item.longitude,
    latitude: item.latitude,
    }});

Comment: The request is a jsonp, and below that Getdata1 variable, I make the request of the lat and lng

Comment: Sounds like a new/different question. That would make it possible to post a new [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (posting code in comments isn't particularly useful)